# Errors when packaging Azure project if Content SourceDirectory contain similar files

Tags: azure

I'm trying to use the SourceDirectory functionality in the Service Definition file to copy first the contents of a "Base" directory into the web role, and then the contents of "AdditionalFiles".  This works fine for debugging in Azure, however when packaging the solution I get an Accessed Denied error when packaging the solution if the AdditionalFiles folder includes a file at the same location as in the Base directory.

> Error 7   Access to the path 'C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\vo0niiyx.rvt\roles\TestWebRole1\approot\connectionStrings.config' is denied.   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Windows Azure Tools\1.5\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets  2

To put this in context, I'm working on migrating an existing app into running in Azure.  The first step I'm doing is to simply wrap the existing functionality so that it will simply *run* in azure.  Additionally the original codebase is rapidly changing so I want to keep my wrapping customisations very seperate to avoid having to continually deal with merging etc.  Up until now, I've been dealing with this through some complicated powershell build scripts.

For reference, below are both the ServiceDefinition file I'm using, as well the directory structure of my solution.  I have also encountered the same issue when using a Worker Role.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="AzureSourceDirectoryTest" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition">
  <WebRole name="TestWebRole1" vmsize="ExtraSmall">
    <Contents>
      <Content destination=".">
        <SourceDirectory path="../Base" />
      </Content>
      <Content destination=".">
        <SourceDirectory path="../AdditionalFiles" />
      </Content>
    </Contents>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint protocol="http" port="80" name="Http" />
    </Endpoints>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

And the directory structure (based upon the output of the tree command, with contents of bin and obj folders removed):

```
│   AzureSourceDirectoryTest.sln
│   
├───AdditionalFiles
│       connectionStrings.config
│       
├───AzureSourceDirectoryTest
│   │   AzureSourceDirectoryTest.ccproj
│   │   AzureSourceDirectoryTest.ccproj.user
│   │   ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg
│   │   ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg
│   │   ServiceDefinition.build.csdef
│   │   ServiceDefinition.csdef
│   ├───bin...                              
│   └───obj...
│
├───Base
│       connectionStrings.config
│       
└───TestWebRole1
    │   TestWebRole1.csproj
    │   TestWebRole1.csproj.user
    │   
    ├───bin...
    ├───obj...
    └───Properties
            AssemblyInfo.cs
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what this *should* do. Which connectionStrings.config should actually get included? My guess would be that it's being copied from two different locations at the same time, and one is failing due to the concurrent access. Can I ask why you're copying the same file twice?

Comment: The scenario I'm in is that I'm wrapping an existing app to run in Azure.  I therefore am trying to keep my modifications separate to the actual application by:

1) Copy the base application into the Web Role
2) Copy my additions on top of what was copied in 1

When simply debugging through Visual Studio, the above works fine as expected (although with a compiler warning saying that the connectionstrings.config file was replaced)

It is only when publishing / deploying that I get this access denied error.